# When does Resharper want me to specify a culture in calls to ToString()?

Tags: resharper, tostring

It appears to be inconsistent.

```
Foo.ToString();
```

Sometimes triggers the warning "Specify a culture in string conversion explicitly" and sometimes it doesn't.

Does anyone know what rules apply here?

Comment: Can you give examples of what Foo is in each case

Comment: Decimals mostly, and in some files / classes the warning is given, and in some not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe when a ToString() method has format dependency (IFormatProvider etc.), ReSharper warns "Specify a culture in string conversion explicitly". On the other hand, if the class has a custom ToString() without any dependency on culture or format then Resharper won't give a warning.

So this will always give a warning:

```cs
int i = 1;
i.ToString();
```

but this will not give any warnings:

```cs
class Foo { 

    public string ToString() { 
        return string.Empty; 
    } 
}; 

var foo = new Foo(); 
foo.ToString();
```